# Spring Data JPA transaction issue

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

My code, really, really simplified looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9.\\s]+$", message="only letters, numbers, spaces and {.!}!")
    private String name;

    // getter, setter
}
```

My Jpa Repository:

```
public interface ItemJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Integer>{}
```

My Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ItemService {

    @Autowired
    ItemDAO itemDAO;

    @Autowired
    ItemJpaRepository itemJpaRepository;

    public void saveOrUpdateItem(){
        itemDAO.saveOrUpdateItem(); //working
        itemJpaRepository.save(entity) //not working
    }

    public void findAllItems(){
        System.out.println(itemJpaRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

Beans that are used for database connection are declared like this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shoppingcartspringmvcspringdatahibernate");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("Scholl1313.");
    //dataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(getDataSource());
    sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.zdranganele.models");
    sessionBuilder.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    sessionBuilder.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    sessionBuilder.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {

    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(getSessionFactory());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.zdranganele.models");

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
```

`ItemDao` is a classic DAO. Saving by `ItemDao` works, saving by `ItemJpaRepository` does not. Also for delete. Only find works on `ItemJpaRepository`. No error are thrown, so I guess it's something that the transaction is never committed.

Comment: Not working because.... what?

Comment: @Antoniossss saving doesn't persist the entity to database. Also deleting doesn't delete an entity from database. I'm only able to get objects from database with findOne() or findAll()

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `@EnableJpaRepositories` in your configuration? Im assuming you are using Spring boot so annotate application's main class (where you got eg. `@EnableAutoconfigure`)

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html